# Override Django filter when searching for list of values in one property

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have simple GroupViewSet, which allows to filter Group objects by id and parent. Everything works as expected.

I would like to expand functionality by allowing filter by multiple parents. Something like /api/groups/?parent=1&parent=2.

The problem is that returned list is filtered only by last provided parent value. So in my example returned queryset will be filtered by parent=2. How can I override filter for list of values while preserving its other functionality.

```
class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_fields = ('id', 'parent')

    def get_queryset(self):
        parent_ids = self.request.query_params.getlist('parent')
        if len(parent_ids) > 1:
            return self.queryset.filter(parent__in=parent_ids)
        return self.queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple way is to declare the FilterSet instead of using the shortcuts.
You'll be able to define the lookup.
Since FilterSet uses Form behind the hood, the list of parameters should be handled properly

```
class GroupFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = {
            'id': ['exact'],
            'parent': ['in'],
        }


class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = GroupFilter
```